# How to add Row [ Row contains input fields ] in antd table React JS?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Iam having a table which contains the following column heading **Name, Age** and i have a button with name Insert Row, while clicking it it should populate two input fields for Name and age. and iam having a button named "SAVE" which should give all the input fields value in console.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I guess you started learning ReactJS directly. Advising to learn Javascript a little before you start.

Comment: no i know JS, Kindly help me in this